# I get a sdk error when trying to install flutter

Tags: android, arp, nt

(flutter doctor --android-licenses) when I write this code I get the following error
[[enter image description here]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/euRv7.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JO5KM.png)

I downloaded sdk command line tools and it still gives the same error
I also edited the system environment variables installed in my folder src and installed flutter and dart in visual studio code but the error is still the same. I found some stuff about it on the internet, but it didn't work.